# BufferedReader.readline() works only once

Tags: android, sockets, tcpclient

I am trying to create an android application which behaves like a client, the problem I am facing is, while receiving string data from the server, app receives it only for the first time. And app receives data again when I reconnect the socket.

I am using socket protocol app as server, I am sending a new line character at the end of the message, and even the connection is alive as I can send data back to the server.

Here's the code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Thread m_thread;
Socket clientSocket;
PrintWriter out;
boolean fan=false,socket=false,light1=false,light2=false,m_run=false;
int quantity = 0;
String msg;
BufferedReader in = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void Start(View view) {
    m_thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            m_run = true;
            try {
                clientSocket = new Socket("192.168.1.34", 2001);
                try {
                    out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new       OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream())));
                    out.println("Client Connected");
                    out.flush();
                    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                    TextView srv_message = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.messageTextView);
                    while(m_run)
                    {
                        if(msg!=null)
                        {

                            srv_message.setText(""+msg);
                        }
                        msg = null;
                    }
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    m_thread.start();
}
```

Start method is called when I click the create connection button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Use this code, it also works for me.

```
input =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
{
            try
            {
                read = input.readLine();
                if (read != null) {
                    // take a handler to Toast the message
                }
            } 
           catch (Exception e) 
           {
                e.printStackTrace();
           }
}
```

Comment: another thing is, when I send a message from this app to the server, server app receives message twice.  It receives "client connected" twice. Can you suggest some changes

Comment: i was also faced same problem follow this link :  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QVq2IGg5ZFM

Answer (score 0):

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    result.append(line);
}

 srv_message.setText(""+result);
```